# Magento 2 error occurs when using <preference> to override a block class

Tags: magento-2.1.3, customer-address, override-block

I want to override the block class `Book.php` of customer module,But i got Following error.

> Recoverable Error: Argument 2 passed to
>   Magento\Customer\Block\Address\Book::__construct() must implement
>   interface Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface, array
>   given, called in
>
> E:\xampp\htdocs\magento217\app\code\MyCompany\MyModule\Block\Rewrite\Address\Book.php
>   on line 67 and defined in
>
> E:\xampp\htdocs\magento217\vendor\magento\module-customer\Block\Address\Book.php
>   on line 55

My **di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">

<preference for="Magento\Customer\Block\Address\Book" type="MyCompany\MyModule\Block\Rewrite\Address\Book" />

</config>
```

**Book.php**

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2013-2017 Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace MyCompany\MyModule\Block\Rewrite\Address;

use Magento\Customer\Api\AddressRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Address\Mapper;

/**
 * Customer address book block
 *
 * @author      Magento Core Team <core@magentocommerce.com>
 */
class Book extends \Magento\Customer\Block\Address\Book
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Customer\Helper\Session\CurrentCustomer
     */
    protected $currentCustomer;

    /**
     * @var CustomerRepositoryInterface
     */
    protected $customerRepository;

    /**
     * @var AddressRepositoryInterface
     */
    protected $addressRepository;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Customer\Model\Address\Config
     */
    protected $_addressConfig;

    /**
     * @var Mapper
     */
    protected $addressMapper;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context
     * @param CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepository
     * @param AddressRepositoryInterface $addressRepository
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Helper\Session\CurrentCustomer $currentCustomer
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Model\Address\Config $addressConfig
     * @param Mapper $addressMapper
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepository,
        AddressRepositoryInterface $addressRepository,
        \Magento\Customer\Helper\Session\CurrentCustomer $currentCustomer,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Address\Config $addressConfig,
        Mapper $addressMapper
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->customerRepository = $customerRepository;
        $this->currentCustomer = $currentCustomer;
        $this->addressRepository = $addressRepository;
        $this->_addressConfig = $addressConfig;
        $this->addressMapper = $addressMapper;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    /**
     * @return $this
     */
    protected function _prepareLayout()
    {
        $this->pageConfig->getTitle()->set(__('Address Book'));
        return parent::_prepareLayout();
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getAddAddressUrl()
    {
        return $this->getUrl('customer/address/new', ['_secure' => true]);
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getBackUrl()
    {
        if ($this->getRefererUrl()) {
            return $this->getRefererUrl();
        }
        return $this->getUrl('customer/account/', ['_secure' => true]);
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getDeleteUrl()
    {
        return $this->getUrl('customer/address/delete');
    }

    /**
     * @param int $addressId
     * @return string
     */
    public function getAddressEditUrl($addressId)
    {
        return $this->getUrl('customer/address/edit', ['_secure' => true, 'id' => $addressId]);
    }

    /**
     * @return bool
     */
    public function hasPrimaryAddress()
    {
        return $this->getDefaultBilling() || $this->getDefaultShipping();
    }

    /**
     * @return \Magento\Customer\Api\Data\AddressInterface[]|bool
     */
    public function getAdditionalAddresses()
    {
        try {
            $addresses = $this->customerRepository->getById($this->currentCustomer->getCustomerId())->getAddresses();
        } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException $e) {
            return false;
        }
        $primaryAddressIds = [$this->getDefaultBilling(), $this->getDefaultShipping()];
        foreach ($addresses as $address) {
            if (!in_array($address->getId(), $primaryAddressIds)) {
                $additional[] = $address;
            }
        }
        return empty($additional) ? false : $additional;
    }

    /**
     * Render an address as HTML and return the result
     *
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Api\Data\AddressInterface $address
     * @return string
     */
    public function getAddressHtml(\Magento\Customer\Api\Data\AddressInterface $address = null)
    {
        if ($address !== null) {
            /** @var \Magento\Customer\Block\Address\Renderer\RendererInterface $renderer */
            $renderer = $this->_addressConfig->getFormatByCode('html')->getRenderer();
            return $renderer->renderArray($this->addressMapper->toFlatArray($address));
        }
        return '';
    }

    /**
     * @return \Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterface|null
     */
    public function getCustomer()
    {
        $customer = $this->getData('customer');
        if ($customer === null) {
            try {
                $customer = $this->customerRepository->getById($this->currentCustomer->getCustomerId());
            } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException $e) {
                return null;
            }
            $this->setData('customer', $customer);
        }
        return $customer;
    }

    /**
     * @return int|null
     */
    public function getDefaultBilling()
    {
        $customer = $this->getCustomer();
        if ($customer === null) {
            return null;
        } else {
            return $customer->getDefaultBilling();
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param int $addressId
     * @return \Magento\Customer\Api\Data\AddressInterface|null
     */
    public function getAddressById($addressId)
    {
        try {
            return $this->addressRepository->getById($addressId);
        } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException $e) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    /**
     * @return int|null
     */
    public function getDefaultShipping()
    {
        $customer = $this->getCustomer();
        if ($customer === null) {
            return null;
        } else {
            return $customer->getDefaultShipping();
        }
    }
}
```

Can any one help me on this problem ? Any references or suggestions are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace your **__construct** by following code

```
/**
 * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context
 * @param CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepository
 * @param AddressRepositoryInterface $addressRepository
 * @param \Magento\Customer\Helper\Session\CurrentCustomer $currentCustomer
 * @param \Magento\Customer\Model\Address\Config $addressConfig
 * @param Mapper $addressMapper
 * @param array $data
 */
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
    CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepository,
    AddressRepositoryInterface $addressRepository,
    \Magento\Customer\Helper\Session\CurrentCustomer $currentCustomer,
    \Magento\Customer\Model\Address\Config $addressConfig,
    Mapper $addressMapper,
    array $data = []
) {
    $this->customerRepository = $customerRepository;
    $this->currentCustomer = $currentCustomer;
    $this->addressRepository = $addressRepository;
    $this->_addressConfig = $addressConfig;
    $this->addressMapper = $addressMapper;
    parent::__construct($context, $customerRepository, $addressRepository, $currentCustomer, $addressConfig, $addressMapper, $data);
}
```

Delete **var/generation/***

**[Update]**

Inside layout config **customer_address_index.xml**, template attribute should be **Magento_Customer::address/book.phtml**

```
<block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Address\Book" name="address_book" template="Magento_Customer::address/book.phtml" cacheable="false"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but other method like getDefaultShipping() is not working.

Comment: Please can you help on that ..?

Comment: What you mean 'getDefaultShipping() is not working' ?

Comment: I want to simply override the getDefaultShipping() methods, i put the exit but it's not working ,only _prepareLayout() is woking.

Comment: It's working fine. See latest update answer.